# Trying to flush database upon app reinstall - Titanium alloy

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, titanium-alloy

Here is my code:

```
if (!Ti.App.Properties.hasProperty('installed')) {

    alert('This is my first run');

    //check first installed
    Ti.App.Properties.setBool('installed', 1);

    //store version number in Ti.App.Properties
    Ti.App.Properties.setString('currentVersion', Titanium.App.version);

    //import DB from Titanium's Resources directory or one of its descendants, if exist

    //create DB
    createDB();

}

//check app version
checkAppVersion();

function createDB() {

    //createDB 
    var db = Ti.Database.open('appdb');
    alert('db created');

    db.close();

}

function checkAppVersion() {

    alert(Titanium.App.version);
    var curversion = Titanium.App.Properties.getString('currentVersion');
    var appversion = Titanium.App.version;

    if (curversion != appversion) {

        //flush database
        alert('flush database');
        flushDb();

    } else {

        //leave existing database
        alert('leave database alone!');


    }

}

function flushDb() {

    // Get database object reference to previous database, if any.
    // If it did not exist previously, this will create a new empty db.
    var dbOld = Ti.Database.open('appdb');

    // Now remove the database, whether it existed before or we just
    // created it above.  The remove() method requires a database object
    // reference, so we had to start by opening it above.
    dbOld.remove();
    dbOld.close();

    // At this point, whether or not there was a previous database it
    // is now gone.  
        //store version number in Ti.App.Properties
    Ti.App.Properties.setString('currentVersion', Titanium.App.version);

    //create DB 
    createDB(); 
}
```

Code works like this:

If app is freshly installed. Create a DB, set version and run app. Alloy models are then executed and everything runs fine.

The problem is when I flush the DB after a version change, I get a SQL error, complaining a table cannot be found after I have deleted it. Even though I have done a fresh reinstall of the DB.

To get it to work I have to quit app and reopen it. I have no idea why this is happening and I am pretty stuck.

**UPDATE:**

Coded a solution for this problem, but I am not happy with it.

When flushing the database, instead of deleting the database, I deleted all of the tables. And then in create DB, I basically called an SQL query to create the tables.

The problem here is that if I ever updated my models, I will have to update the schema in two places.

If anyone has a better solution, do let me know, cheers.

Comment: Have you tried migrations?

Comment: I have had a look at them, but I couldn't really understand why it would be a better way to do things as I will still need to change the db schema, within the migration code

Comment: The migrations allow you to keep the same DB schema across all the versions of your app, so let's say you have users on version 1.1 and some on 1.2 than you push the 1.3 update, now when it's downloaded both the 1.1 users and the 1.2 will have the most current version of your DB. So no need to flush the DB ever.

Comment: Take a look at this and make a quick small app to try it out: [Alloy Migrations](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Sync_Adapters_and_Migrations-section-36739597_AlloySyncAdaptersandMigrations-Migrations)

Comment: Will this work if I change my alloy models (or work at all with alloy models), i.e. add another column?

Comment: Yes, this is meant to keep the Alloy models in sync from one DB version to another, so if you add a column to a model you would create another migration file with that column added.

Comment: ok great - will have a look